# Insert a 0"zero" infront of number for specify number sequences

Tags: excel

I have this data

```
Name | Code | Price
XXX     102    1000
YYY    4321    1150
ZZZ     202    1150
AAA     123    1000
```

I can now Add concatenate and Add 0 in front of Code which makes

```
0102
04321
0202
0123
```

Now here the problem lies. I dont want that 0 in front of 4321 . I want 0 only infront of 3 digit numbers not more than 3 digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on Column, go to Format cell-->Custom and write 0000 in the type and click on Ok

Simplest and easy solution

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the '102' data is located at B2, just type :

```
=IF(len(B2)<=3,"0"&B2,B2)
```

will do. Alternatively, using `concatenate()` function you may do it like this :

```
=IF(len(B2)<=3,CONCATENATE("0"&B2),B2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but its solved without array

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have codes in B column

```
if(len(b2)=3,concatenate("0",b2),b2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the time. But I got the simpliest answer . Really sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write formula then this would be better,

> =REPT(0,4-LEN(A1))&A1